# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 - flutter Groovy error

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to run the app  , but it gave me this error < how to fix it guys !!! i tried everthing but nothig realy wordked ..

-changing flutter versions
-downgrde flutter
-gradle versions
nothing worked

[image]

how can fix it
my - Flutter 3.16.2 - Dart 3.2.2

- [link](https://github.com/MoHatim-Tech/gradle-error)those are my files build.gradle and pubspec.yaml I'm using Android studio

Comment: Please share your build.gradle and pubspec.yaml files.

Comment: **[link](https://github.com/MoHatim-Tech/gradle-error)
@tomerpacific those is the files**

Comment: Please edit your question and add those to it.

Comment: @tomerpacific I did, so what next?